# Use CSS custom property within url data type

Tags: css, css-variables

I have a custom property `--src: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100'` which I would like to insert into a url() of a background image.

I thought that something like this would work ...

```
.custom {
  --image: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(var(--src));
}
```

but it doesn't.

```css
.custom {
  --image: 'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
   /*  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100x100');it should look like this */
  background-image: url(var(--image)); /* this doesn't work */
  
}
```

```html
<div class="custom" style="--image:'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100';">hello</div>
```

I skimmed through the spec on [url()](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#url-value) and [custom properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/), but couldn't find anything which says that url() doesn't support custom properties.

Just to add some context as to why I'm trying to this:

I was trying to add the background-image in a pseudo-element to save the extra element. (It doesn't work)

```css
div:before {
  content: var(--image); /* this works */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(var(--image)); /* this doesn't */
}
```

```html
<div style="--image:'http://via.placeholder.com/100x100';"></div>
```

So is this possible, or am i missing something?